# Kiosk Mode Browser in Windows 10 Home

Tags: windows-10, browser, kiosk

I know there is a Kiosk Mode (previously Assigned User) in Windows 10 Pro, but is there any way to accomplish it in Windows 10 Home? I'd prefer Chrome, but I'm open to another browser.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect (ALT + F4 will exit) but you can run Chrome in Kiosk mode. [Create a new Chrome shortcut then add --kiosk to the command line arguments for said shortcut](https://lifehacker.com/use-chromes-kiosk-mode-to-limit-someones-access-to-yo-1243433249).

Answer (score 0):

Open up Chrome's settings

Under "Users" click "Add new user."

Give the new profile a name and picture. Make sure "Create a desktop shortcut for this user" is checked. Click "Create."

Right-click the newly-created shortcut and select "Properties."

In the "Target" field, add "--kiosk" (no quotes) to the end.

Click "Apply."

Now all you have to do is be sure they use that shortcut you created.

[Source of information](https://lifehacker.com/use-chromes-kiosk-mode-to-limit-someones-access-to-yo-1243433249)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. None of the "--kiosk" answers worked for me. I'm not sure why.

What ended up working for my particular needs was creating a simple Electron.js app, which lets you make enter kiosk mode as well as many other useful features for kiosks.